# Duplicate entry for primary key Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am doing a many to many relationship with Entity Framework Core and I am encountering a problem with the primary keys. I have two classes named Ingredient and Item and then I have a class named ItemIngredient and the first entry with itemid 1 and ingredientid 1 was okay. Then I tried to add another itemingredient with itemid 1 and ingredientid 2 and this is what happened. Both id's exist and the program reads them correctly, the problem is in the relationships.

[image]
Here is my code:
part of my DataContext:`

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<ItemIngredient>()
                .HasKey(bc => new { bc.ItemId, bc.IngredientId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemIngredient>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Item)
                .WithMany(b => b.ItemIngredients)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ItemIngredient>()
                .HasOne(bc => bc.Ingredient)
                .WithMany(c => c.ItemIngredients)
                .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.Id);
}
```

item.cs

```
using DTO;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CateringApp
{
    public class Item
    {
        public enum ItemType
        {
            Food,
            Drinks
        }

        public enum OrderStatus
        {
            Preparing,
            Cooking,
            Ready
        }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public ItemType itemType { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ItemOrder> ItemOrder { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ItemIngredient> ItemIngredients { get; set; }

       
    }
}
```

ingredient.cs

```
using DTO;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CateringApp
{
    public class Ingredient
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ItemIngredient> ItemIngredients { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ItemIngredient.cs

```
using CateringApp;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DTO
{

    public class ItemIngredient
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public Ingredient Ingredient {get; set;}

    }
}
```

Comment: Error is obvious, you are trying to insert an Ingredient with Primary Key 1 again

Comment: what is your relationship and entity's name? It's confusing here, As you said its many to many relationships, so dies it means an Item has multiple ingredients and an ingredient has multiple items?

Comment: @viveknuna well that is what I want but I set it as a Foreign key, why does it give me an error?